# Drill profile queries

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-drill

Im using Drill in my hadoop cluster, having drillbits across all nodes. Currently im using Drill to query Hive tables and i need to know the exact query execution time. For a more friendy approach, i started to use the Drill Web UI available on port 8047 and i run the queries and then i cant access the profile part to see how much time it took.

The problem is that sometimes the queries result dont show on the list of the profile page.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because each Drillbit only has the profile for the queries it was the Foreman for. Going into a bit more detail, when you run a Drill query from the command line the following happens:

1. You enter **Query A** on the cli.
2. The cli picks a Drillbit to be the Foreman for **Query A**. The Foreman is the Drillbit that coordinates running the query. *Note:* each query can have a different Foreman.
3. **Query A** runs and **Query A**'s Foreman stores the profile **locally**. This means **Query A**'s profile will only be available on it's Foreman, if you go to a different Drillbit it will not have a profile for **Query A**.

The only real solution for this is that you will have to check each Drillbit in the cluster to see which one has the profile for your query, or to have one Drillbit be the designated Foreman for all queries.